# how to replace item in list if the title already exists in the text file?

Tags: python, html

So basically I'm trying to make it so that if the user puts in a title in the form that matches a title in the list, it replaces that title and it's content. But I don't know how to do that.

```python
@route('/update', method="POST")
def update_article():
    """
    Receives page title and contents from a form, and creates/updates a
    text file for that page.
    """

    title = getattr(request.forms, "title")
    content = getattr(request.forms, "content")


    articles = read_articles_from_file()
    articles.append({
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    })

    my_file = open("storage/articles.json", "w")
    my_file.write(json.dumps(articles, indent=3))
    my_file.close()

    return redirect('/wiki/<pagename>')
```

Comment: you mean you want to check if title is in articles (output of read_articles_from_file())?

Comment: if the title entered by the user is already in the list, then whats the point in replacing the title? i think the content to be replaced is enough. Also please share more details on form html and the page you want to display next

Comment: for i, article in enumerate(articles): if title == article['title']: articles[i]['content'] = content

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfvNfbC3qKk this is what I'm trying to achieve @mukundghode

Comment: for i, article in enumerate(articles):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'articles' referenced before assignment
@ABC

Comment: do that after the line `articles = read_articles_from_file()`

Comment: added an answer for what i meant. @Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this: (not too elegant way tho)

```
...
articles = read_articles_from_file()

append_flag = True
for i, article in enumerate(articles):      # loop through existing articles
    if title == article['title']:           # if new title is already exists 
        articles[i]['content'] = content    # update content of that article
        append_flag = False                 # update flag to false
        break                               # break the loop, assumed title is unique 

if append_flag:                             # append new record 
    articles.append({
        "title": title.strip(),             # strip out spaces, to ensure str==str comparison for content updates 
        "content": content
    })
...
```